# Bad notification for startForeground when sound started play

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to make an alarm clock, but it gives an error when the ringtone is about to play.
an error "  android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification for startForeground"
When I tested on Android 8 everything worked correctly, only on higher Android this problem occurs..............................................................

**AlarmService**

```
public class AlarmService extends Service {
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private Vibrator vibrator;
Alarm alarm;
Uri ringtone;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    ringtone= RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this.getBaseContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Bundle bundle=intent.getBundleExtra(getString(R.string.bundle_alarm_obj));
    if (bundle!=null)
        alarm =(Alarm)bundle.getSerializable(getString(R.string.arg_alarm_obj));
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, RingActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(getString(R.string.bundle_alarm_obj),bundle);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    String alarmTitle=getString(R.string.alarm_title);
    if(alarm!=null) {
        alarmTitle = alarm.getTitle();
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this.getBaseContext(), Uri.parse(alarm.getTone()));
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else{

        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this.getBaseContext(),ringtone);
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Ring Ring .. Ring Ring")
            .setContentText(alarmTitle)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alarm_white_24dp)
            .setSound(null)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_ALARM)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent,true)
            .build();
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });

    if(alarm.isVibrate()) {
        long[] pattern = {0, 100, 1000};
        vibrator.vibrate(pattern, 0);
    }
    startForeground(1, notification);

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

**App**

```
public class App extends Application {
public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "ALARM_SERVICE_CHANNEL";
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    createNotificationChannnel();

    sharedPreferences= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean dn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(getString(R.string.dayNightTheme), true);
    if (dn) {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
    } else {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
    }
}

private void createNotificationChannnel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                getString(R.string.app_name)+"Service Channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        );

        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you double check your paste? The notification in the AlarmService is floating with a random @Override so it looks like we're missing a chunk.

Comment: @DanHarms I added the whole thing

Comment: Do you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />` in your manifest?

Comment: @DanHarms yes i have

Comment: Only other thing I can think of off the top of my head is calling `startForeground()` before using mediaPlayer and vibrator.